# Parsing custom fields with Cassava and Attoparsec

Tags: csv, parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I have a CSV with fields in it which contain unit values which I have to parse out. As a simple example:

```
data EValue = Farads Double | MicroFarads Double | PicoFarads Double
```

Thus I need to parse something like the following:

```
parseEValue = farads <|> micro <|> pico
  where farads = Farads <$> double <* string "F"
        micro  = MicroFarads <$> double <* string "µF"
        pico   = PicoFarads <$> double <* string "pF"
```

How do I include this in an instance definition for `FromField` for `Cassava`?

```
instance FromField EValue where
  parseField = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to run attoparsec on the `Field` you get and then put the result in the `Parser` monad, like this: `parseField = either fail pure . parseOnly parseEValue`.

For completeness, here's full working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
import Data.Csv

data EValue = Farads Double | MicroFarads Double | PicoFarads Double

parseEValue = farads <|> micro <|> pico
  where farads = Farads <$> double <* string "F"
        micro  = MicroFarads <$> double <* string "µF"
        pico   = PicoFarads <$> double <* string "pF"

instance FromField EValue where
  parseField = either fail pure . parseOnly parseEValue
```